# CS50 Credit Assignment - Floating Point Exception

Tags: c, cs50

any ideas why this is generating a floating point exception? Please ignore the bad coding. This is very rough and I am just trying to experiment different things on this assignment. Also, I trying to do this assignment with only the operations learned in class (I am awere there are others that would make this easier)

Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{   long c = get_long("What is your credit card number?\n");
    long i = 10;
    long j = 100;
    long n = 0;
    long m = 0;
    long x = 2;
    do
    {   long a = (c % i - (c % i)/10)/(i/10);
        n = a + n;
        i = i*100;
    }
    while (c/i >= 0.1 || c/i == 0);
    do
    {   long b = (c%j - (c%j)/10)/(j/10);
        m = b + m;
        j = j*100;
    }
    while (c/j >= 0.1 || c/j == 0);

    long sum = n + 2*m;

    if (i > j)
    {   
        x = i;
    }

    else
    {   
        x = j;
    }

    if (sum % 10 == 0)
    {   if((x == 10000000000000000) && ((c % (x/100) - c % (x/1000))/(x/100000) == (34)))
        {
            printf("Amercan Express\n");
        }
        else if((x  == 100000000000000000) && ((c % (x/100) - c % (x/1000))/(x/100000) == (51)))
        {
            printf("MasterCard\n");
        }
        else if((x == 10000000000000) && ((c % (x/100) - c % (x/1000))/(x/100000) == 4))
        {
            printf("Visa\n");
        }
        else if((x == 10000000000000000) && ((c % (x/100) - c % (x/1000))/(x/100000) == 4))
        {
            printf("Visa\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Invlid\n");
        }
    }

    else
    {
        printf("Invlid\n");
    }   
}'''
```

Comment: Where do you get the error when you enter what? And what is the __verbatim__ error message? [Edit] your question and make that clear _there_. Read this: [ask]

Comment: This would be a great first try at using a debugger, to break at the exception and see why it arises.

Comment: Hint: you should treat the credit card number as a string. The code would be so much simpler

Answer (score 0):

This is the part that is the problem:

while (c/i >= 0.1 || c/i == 0);

in your first do while loop.

Your data types are long and so you are saying that as long as c/i is greater than 0.1 or == 0 then keep going. Unfortunately this will go on forever as a long will always be >= 0.1 or <= 0 because it cant hold decimal places.If you play around with debug50 by using debug50 ./filename you can place a red dot and step through. What you will see is the first do while loop will keep running increasing the value of i every cycle. Eventually the value of i is bigger than the memory limit for a long and so the code creates unexpected results.If you step through you find that it eventually assigns 0 to i and so you suffer a divide by 0 error.

You can fix this by changing data types or altering that while loop.

I hope that helps. Id suggest stepping through that do while loop using debug50 in the cs50 ide to see whats going on.

Comment: To clarify the first part. A long divided by a long returns a long. I think you are expecting it to return a float as you are using >= 0.1. A long will not store an decimal values.